# php specifying Cache-Control results in double max-age

Tags: php

When I specify:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=31557600');
```

the result header is

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31557600, max-age=0
```

It seems to still work, but it seems what php is doing is combining my Cache-Control header with what it sends if I don't specify the header.

Is there a way to nuke the second max-age=0 in php?

Comment: Have you tried setting the second parameter for `header` to true and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Yes, it has no effect. And I've tried header_remove first and that just results in no Cache-Control header at all.

Comment: Do a `var_dump(headers_list());` after your `header` call – is the header messed up in the result of that already? Otherwise it might not be PHP doing something wrong here, but it gets mangled later on by the web server or during transfer.

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> string(31) "Cache-Control: max-age=31557600" [1]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 15:03:40 GMT" [2]=> string(35) "Etag: "c05223-819-54eb414c-749cadb"" [3]=> string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding" }

Comment: So it appears it is Apache adding that?

Comment: Looks like that  (you could make that debug output again at the very “end” of your script, to be sure) … either the web server, or some other party along the transport chain (f.e. a proxy).

Comment: has to be apache as that result came from localhost ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was mod_expires

When mod_expires is active, and the line

```
ExpiresDefault A0
```

is present, it will put max-age=0 on anything that doesn't match one of its ExpiresByType directives.

So if using a php wrapper for something you want browsers to cache, don't set ExpiresDefault to anything and make sure there is not an ExpiresByType set for the same mime type.